# Servlet - close connection but not method

Tags: java, servlets

I have to implements service (servlet 2.5 or 3) that will send `204` code on every connection but not close the thread. 
I need do some stuff with the data I received (like open new connection).

It is possible to close connection but not end method? Or start another method when connection is closing?

Comment: Like starting a new thread to perform additional processing?

Comment: Yep, but first must be send 204, then action. With new thread is problem, because action can be run first.

Comment: No, it'll be run in parallel. You can put a delay, so it'll be run after 2 seconds for example.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is unclear in the specs, but it seems to work in Tomcat 7.0.

Extract from the specs for servlet 3.0 :

> Closure of Response Object
>   When a response is closed, the container must immediately flush all remaining
>   content in the response buffer to the client. The following events indicate that the
>   servlet has satisfied the request and that the response object is to be closed:
>
> - The termination of the service method of the servlet.
> - The amount of content specified in the setContentLength method of the response
>     has been greater than zero and has been written to the response.
> - The sendError method is called.
> - The sendRedirect method is called.
> - The complete method on AsyncContext is called.

From my tests on a tomcat 7.0.32, the Http connection is closed before the end of the `service` method of the servlet when ContentLength is set to 0 **and** the output stream is closed.

So per you requirements, you could try the following in your servlet :

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
response.setContentLength(0);
response.getOutputStream().close();
// continue after connection with client is closed
```

But **BEWARE** I could find no confirmation in the specs so it could not work with another container.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException {
        //Send 204 back
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
        // Continue with you logic here
        .
        .
        .
        .
```