# Send status 200 without having to wait any return

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a GET request in my API that can be called via url. My problem is that this request is waiting for some return, even though it may take indefinitely. I would like to return a 200 status code right at the beginning of the application so that the user does not have his page blocked waiting for a response, while the rest of the code is executed normally.

My actual code look like this:

```
@Controller
public class APITest {

    @RequestMapping(value="test", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public void RequestTest(
                @RequestParam(value="token", required=false) String token, 
                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws InterruptedException, ParseException, IOException, SQLException {

            // SOME CODE HERE

            return;
        }   
}
```

Is what I need possible using this method?

Comment: How about using `@Async` methods? See this [Getting Started](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/) article.

Comment: This remembers me an old [post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25402616/3545273). You should try to set the status and close the output stream of the response.

Comment: Thank you @SergeBallesta this worked fine for me! Exactly what I need. Despite the answer from Stephan worked as well, your method is simpler. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run the code in a different thread.

```
@Controller
public class APITest {

    @RequestMapping(value="test", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public void RequestTest(
                @RequestParam(value="token", required=false) String token, 
                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws InterruptedException, ParseException, IOException, SQLException {

            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> longRunningTask());

            return;
        }   
}
```

The `longRunningTask()` will be executed in a different thread and `RequestTest()` will return directly with a 200.